# Limit of a function and it's derivative

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Can $f(x)$ tend to infinity and $f'(x)$ tend to zero when $x$ tends to $+\infty$?

Comment: Try $f(x)=\ln(x)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the function $f(x):=\log x$?

Answer (score 1):

How about ?

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

Other examples are $f(x)=x^a$ with $0<a<1$